# Adjuntar videos en comando de discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

tengo el siguiente código quiero reemplazar el requerimiento de "message : str" para pedir un archivo adjunto

```
@commands.hybrid_command(
    name="say",
    description="The bot will say anything you want.",
)
@checks.is_owner()
async def say(self, context: Context, message: str) -> None:
    """
    The bot will say anything you want.
    :param context: The hybrid command context.
    :param message: The message that should be repeated by the bot.
    """
    await context.send(message)
```

aquí esta el lugar donde se adjunta
[image: Sin seleccionar el mensaje]

pero cuando el bot selecciona el comando desaparece esa opción.

[image: después de seleccionar el comando]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simplemente era reemplazar 'message: str' por ['attachment: discord.Attachment'](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-attachment)

```
class Template(commands.Cog, name="template"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="testcommand",
        description="This is a testing command that does nothing.",
    )
    async def testcommand(self, context: Context,attachment: discord.Attachment):

        await context.send(f'You have uploaded <{attachment.url}>')


# And then we finally add the cog to the bot so that it can load, unload, reload and use it's content.
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Template(bot))
```

Comment: await context.send(f'You have uploaded <{attachment.url}>') los "<>" eliminan la imagen, video etc. referencial para solo acceder desde el link